# Simple way to visualize postgres tables in Heroku?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

Is there a simple way to visualize the tables that are created for postgres databases in Heroku? I am trying to see what columns have been for my Rails app without having to go through all of my database migrations.

Comment: Just look at your `schema.rb` file. That is, assuming your local db and Heroku db are migrated to the same state.

Comment: The reason I am having issues is because I deleted some of my db migration files (I know, bad idea) and can only run `heroku run:detached rake db:migrate` which ends up not creating all of the columns I want.

Comment: Have you looked at your schema file?

Comment: Yes, but I am pretty sure the schema file in my development environment is different from my schema file in the production environment. I am getting the following error: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'titleize' for nil:NilClass)` when I am trying to titleize user's first and last names. This is working in my development environment, but not in production which is leading me to think that the schema files are different.

Comment: Nope. The nil error does not suggest a missing relation (table). If the table didn't exist, you'd be getting a missing relation error from the database. And, if the class didn't exist, you'd be getting a constant lookup error.

Comment: I guess you use version control (e.g., git) and push to Heroku via git? Then just go grab the production version of your schema file from your last push. Then you can do a `db:schema:load`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view your tables you can run `heroku pg:psql` to fire up a Postgres console. Then just type `\d` to view your tables or if you want to get details from a particular table just run `\d tablename`.

Or, as @jvillian suggested you can view your `schema.rb` file that's deployed to your Heroku server.

```
$ heroku run bash
$ cat db/schema.rb
```

Comment: Good ones! I'm thinking this is an XY problem, though. "I deleted some migrations and now I'm getting a `NoMethodError` so I infer my tables are messed up..." Doesn't quite sound right, y'know?

Comment: haha absolutely. In terms of "checking" which tables were migrated and which are not `heroku pg:psql` to view them would help right? he then just needs to compare what tables are migrated against his local environment.

Comment: To belabor the point, if he had munged his database and/or models, then he wouldn't be getting the `NoMethodError (undefined method 'titleize' for nil:NilClass)`. That's a missing data problem. Not a missing table/field problem. Or am I thinking about that wrong?

Comment: No I think you're right because if it was a table/field issue you wouldn't get that kind of error correct ?

Comment: Correct. Missing table would give a `missing relation` error at the DB level. Missing column would give `unknown attribute` error. Or some such things. But, not the error he's getting.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the easiest way to solve this problem is to do `heroku pg:psql` and then do `\d users` to look at my table named "users". It turns out I have migrated the columns `first_name` and `last_name`, so I have solved the problem I posted about.

I'm still trying to figure out why I am running into the `NoMethodError (undefined method 'titleize' for nil:NilClass)`. If you are having trouble with this issue and this answer does not help you, check out the comments between jillian and Cyzanfar. They have good insights into how a postgres database works with Heroku.